# My Application get crashed for Barcode Scanning in above iOS 9.3 version

Tags: ios, xcode, camera, avfoundation, avcapturesession

Hi I am trying to develop app for 1D and 2D Barcode scanning, it works well in iOS 9.3 and Xcode 7.3 but when I am trying to run same application in iOS 10 and Xcode 8.2 application get crashed on below line.
Please help on it.

> [_session addOutput:_output];

```
-(void)setupCaptureSession{

    _session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    _device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    NSError *error = nil;

    _input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:_device error:&error];

    if (_input) {
        [_session addInput:_input];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }

    _output = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];

    [_output setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [_session addOutput:_output]; // here Application get crashed.

    _output.metadataObjectTypes = [_output availableMetadataObjectTypes];

    _prevLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:_session];
    _prevLayer.frame = _previewView.bounds;
    _prevLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    [_previewView.layer addSublayer:_prevLayer];
      //[self.view];
    //[_session startRunning];

    [_previewView bringSubviewToFront:_highlightView];

}
```

Comment: What is the exception message associated with the crash?

Comment: First Error printed on Log 1) Error: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11814 "Cannot Record" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try recording again., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Record}                                               2nd Error  Thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Why did you comment this line [_session startRunning]; ?

Comment: I have written same line in View did load method.

Comment: try to uncomment this line and remove it from viewDidLoad.

Comment: I have uncomment you mentioned line and removed from View did Load, but still it crashes.

Comment: Thanks for the code @YogeshRaut in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I have just commented, following code of line:

```
[_previewView.layer addSublayer:_prevLayer];
```

and added below code of line in my app and app works without error:

```
[_previewView.layer insertSublayer:_prevLayer atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add Camera Usage Description to your plist file? If no, take a look on [this](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/privacy-settings-in-ios-10/) blog.

Comment: I have added in plist file, but result is same.

Comment: Your app should ask user permission to access the camera. If not, try to rebuild / reinstall the app. But if it did, then update your question with crash log, please.

Comment: It ask for permission. Following is Crash log.                                        First Error printed on Log 1) Error: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11814 "Cannot Record" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try recording again., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Record}                                               2nd Error  Thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: @YogeshRaut Sorry for the dumb question, but - are you getting this on a real device, right? Or maybe iOS Simulator...

Comment: On both Simulator and on device also.

Answer (score 0):

`iOS 10` requires more privacy with the usage of hardware input sources.
Your app works with a camera, and you need to provide additional explanation of why it needs a camera.

So, go to your `Info.plist` file and add an additional `key-value` pair dictionary there.
For key choose - `Privacy Camera Usage Description`
For value add some string like next - `App needs a camera to make amazing photos, scan barcodes, etc...`

To be sure if everything is Ok, go to `Settings` iOS app and check there for camera toggle switched to `On` for you application.